# Number of solutions for inequality

Tags: equation-solving

Please explain me how can I calculate a number of possible solutions for such inequality and obtain those values:

```
3x + 7y + z <= 198
```

where `x,y,z` are integers.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Inequalities-ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities.html

Comment: brutal force : `Table[If[3 x + 7 y + z <= 198, {x, y, z}, 0], {x, 198}, {y, 198}, {z, 
    198}] // Flatten[#, 2] & // DeleteCases[#, 0] &  //Length`

Comment: Since there's no lower bound on $x,y,z$, there are infinitely many answers.  For example, (- a lot, - a lot, - a lot).  You probably mean to say "... where $x,y,z$ are positive integers."  You may also mean "non-negative".

Answer (score 9):

There are an infinite number of solutions unless you constrain x, y, z more than just to being integers. For example, let {x, y, z} all be negative.

Using the asumption that they are all non-negative

```
Solve[{3 x + 7 y + z <= 198, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0}, {x, y, z}, 
  Integers] // Length

(*  67354  *)
```

Using the asumption that they are all positive

```
Solve[{3 x + 7 y + z <= 198, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x, y, z}, 
  Integers] // Length

(*  57033  *)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to export all of those non-negative solutions to some `*.csv` file for example?

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk Export["solutions.csv", {x,y,z}/.Solve[{3x+7y+z<=198, x>=0, y>=0, z>=0}, {x, y, z}, Integers]]

Comment: Or `Export["solutions.csv", {x,y,z,3x+7y+z}/.Solve[{3x+7y+z<=198, x>=0, y>=0, z>=0}, {x, y, z}, Integers]]` to see the function value as well.

Answer (score 6):

Since you seem to want non-negative solutions, try [FrobeniusSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html), which is built for linear Diophantine problems such as yours. Count such solutions with

```
Sum[Length[FrobeniusSolve[{3, 7, 1}, b]], {b, 0, 198}]
```

and find the solutions with

```
Flatten[Table[FrobeniusSolve[{3, 7, 1}, b], {b, 0, 198}], 1]
```

On multi-core machines, use `ParallelSum` and `ParallelTable` for faster results. See this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85860/how-to-find-the-solutions-to-abcd-60/85861) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
FindInstance[
 3 x + 7 y + z <= 198 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Integers, 5]

{{x -> 43, y -> 9, z -> 5}, {x -> 50, y -> 4, z -> 15}, {x -> 35, y -> 9, z -> 22},
 {x -> 34, y -> 10, z -> 26}, {x -> 24, y -> 17, z -> 3}}
```

verify it

```
3 x + 7 y + z <= 198 /. %
{True, True, True, True, True}
```

If more or less solutions be sought, change the last digit (5)